# Getting multiple results from WHERE clause in PHP

Tags: php, mysql

Please excuse my horrid coding and design aspect of this. I am not too concerned about the look of it as I am of how well it works.

I have 2 tables (Cars, Customers) in which both have the VIN columns. When I add a new car I put in a VIN, and when a customer purchases a vehicle, I select the VIN from a drop-down list that is populated in all cars with the field VSold is set to 'N'. That works great, the issue I have is that when I run the code below, it gives me multiple customer names. When I run a search query in that database for that table and exact VIN, there is only 1 customer that has that matching VIN (I made it UNIQUE), yet in my ugly code, it gives me a bunch of results, all the same car, just different customers. What am I doing wrong here? How can I clean this thing up?

```
<?php
$dbhost = 'localhost';
$dbuser = 'root';
$dbpass = '';

$conn = mysql_connect($dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpass);

if(! $conn ) {
    die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
}

$VIN=$_POST['formVIN'];

$sql = 
  "SELECT 
    Cars.VIN, Cars.VYear, Cars.VMake, Cars.VModel, 
    Cars.VOdometer, Cars.VPurchasedPrice, Cars.VPurchasedDate, 
    Cars.VSold, Cars.VSoldPrice, Cars.VSoldDate, Cars.VSalesPerson, 
    Customers.CustFirst, Customers.CustLast 
  FROM 
    Cars, Customers 
  WHERE Cars.VIN='$VIN'";

mysql_select_db('dbCar2016');
$retval = mysql_query( $sql, $conn );

if(! $retval ) {
die('Could not get data: ' . mysql_error());
}
  while($row = mysql_fetch_array($retval, MYSQL_ASSOC)) {
    echo "Information on record for the VIN provided:<br><br>";
    echo "VIN:" . $row["VIN"] . "<br>";
    echo "Year:" . $row["VYear"] . "<br>";
    echo "Make:" . $row["VMake"] . "<br>";
    echo "Model:" . $row["VModel"] . "<br>";
    echo "Odometer:" . $row["VOdometer"] . "<br>";
    echo "Purchased Price:$" . $row["VPurchasedPrice"] . "<br>";
    echo "Purchased Date:" . $row["VPurchasedDate"] . "<br><br>";
      if ($row["VSold"]=='Y') {
        echo "This Vehicle sold.<br>";
        echo "Price Sold:" . $row["VSoldPrice"] . "<br>";
        echo "Date Sold:" . $row["VSoldDate"] . "<br>";
        echo "Sales Person:" . $row["VSalesPerson"] . "<br><br>";

        echo "It was sold to<br>";
        echo "Customer Name:" . $row["CustFirst"] . " " . $row["CustLast"] . "<br>";
    } else {
        echo "This Vehicle has not sold yet.<br>";
    }
  echo "<p>VIN Successfully Searched</p>";
}
echo "<a href=vinlookup.php>Search Another VIN</a>";
mysql_close($conn);
?>
```

When I put a VIN of a vehichle not sold (VSold='N'), I don't have any issue. (I think...) I tried using a UNION between the tables, but I got even more mixed up.

Thanks ahead of time for the help!

UPDATE:

```
UPDATE 
  Cars SET VSold='Y', 
  VSoldPrice='$VSoldPrice', 
  VSoldDate='$CustDownDate', 
  VSalesPerson='$VSalesPerson' 
WHERE 
  VIN='$VIN'
```

Is what I have on the page that I add customers to. It inputs all the customers information, (CustFirst, CustLast, etc.), to the table Customers. Thus no Customers.VIN will ever be filled out if there was no customer associated with any VIN (Cars.VIN).

Comment: I am impressed there are still people using mysql_* library with no injection checks. `SELECT c.*, 
          b.CustFirst, 
          b.CustLast 
     FROM Cars c
LEFT JOIN Customers b
       ON c.VIN=b.VIN
    WHERE c.VIN = $VIN` or just JOIN depending on whether u want to include results with no buyers or all.

Comment: @Prix then you'll be impressed by a large number of StackOverflow users ;-)

Comment: Cesar - MySQL is now DEPRECATED and no longer supported with PHP7, you should with extreme prejudice stop using it and instead explore MySQLi or PDO. Your code would also develop in leaps and bounds if you researched and began implementing Prepared Statements rather than the current "analogue" implmentation of SQL querying with PHP

Comment: @Martin recently most of the PHP questions I have open were using mysqli, even tough they contained SQL Injection in the code, it was still mysqli been awhile since I open one that is using mysql_*.

Comment: @Prix how does your activities relate to the question set out by Cesar?

Comment: Do cars and customers relate in some way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While all your answers did solve the multiple search results, it was giving me no results if the vehicle wasn't sold, hence no VIN associated with any customer. I decided to go about it through multiple search queries and IF statements. PROBABLY not the most efficient or cleanliness but it works great. Any code improvements are always welcome. Thank for all your guys help!

```
$formVIN = $_POST[formVIN]

sql1= SELECT * FROM Cars WHERE VIN=$formVIN
sql2= SELECT * FROM Customers WHERE VIN=$formVIN

$retval1=mysql_query( $sql1, $conn )
$retval2=mysql_query( $sql2, $conn )

if(! $retval1 ) {
  die('No VIN information.' . mysql_error());
} else {

    while($row1 = mysql_fetch_array($retval1, MYSQL_ASSOC)) {
    echo "<p><b>Information on record for the VIN provided:</b></p>";
    echo "VIN:" . $row1["VIN"] . "<br>";
    echo "Year:" . $row1["VYear"] . "<br>";
    echo "Make:" . $row1["VMake"] . "<br>";
    echo "Model:" . $row1["VModel"] . "<br>";
        if ($row1["VSold"]=='Y') 
        {
            while($row2 = mysql_fetch_array($retval2, MYSQL_ASSOC)) {
            echo "<p><b>This Vehicle sold.</b></p>";
            echo "Price Sold:" . $row1["VSoldPrice"] . "<br>";
            echo "Date Sold:" . $row1["VSoldDate"] . "<br>";
            echo "Sales Person:" . $row1["VSalesPerson"] . "<br>";

            echo "<p><b>It was sold to:</b></p>";
            echo "Customer ID:" . $row2["CustID"] . "<br>";
            echo "Customer Name:" . $row2["CustFirst"] . " " . $rowl["CustLast"] . "<br>";
            }
        } else 
                {
                    echo "<p><b>This Vehicle has not sold yet.</b></p><br>";
                }
}
}
```

Like I said, probably not the most efficient way to go about it, but it works great. Thanks everyone!

Answer (score 0):

If I understood correctly your problem (you have multiple queries returning and not only one), change this:

`WHERE Cars.VIN='$VIN'`

to this

`WHERE Cars.VIN='$VIN' AND Cars.VIN = Customers.VIN`

Comment: Since there is no Customers.VIN set if the VSold is N, it won't give me a result.

Comment: But you wrote `I have 2 tables (Cars, Customers) in which both have the VIN field`. So are you lying ?

Comment: I'm sorry, I meant have a VIN column. The Customer VIN Column is only populated when the VSold Column in the Cars table is set to 'N'. Super ambiguous, I know. I apologize for the misinterpretation.

Comment: So, to my WHERE add `AND VSold = 'N'`

Comment: It works great, way better than what I had, for cars that have been sold and have a link of association with a customer. It doesn't work for cars that still haven't sold and there is no vin association to a customer. I'll keep at it, I know there are tons of flaws. `AND VSold = 'N'` won't work at all. Thanks for your help though! I see some light at the end of the tunnel.

Comment: Remember that you can use `()` to use one clause or other, I mean this: `WHERE (Cars.VIN='$VIN' AND Cars.VIN = Customers.VIN AND VSold = 'N') OR (Other clause that helps you find cars not sold)`

Answer (score 0):

From what it looks like you're trying to do you should be using an inner to get info from both tables.

```
SELECT Cars.VIN, Cars.VYear, Cars.VMake, Cars.VModel, Cars.VOdometer, Cars.VPurchasedPrice, Cars.VPurchasedDate, Cars.VSold, Cars.VSoldPrice, Cars.VSoldDate, Cars.VSalesPerson, Customers.CustFirst, Customers.CustLast 
FROM Cars 
INNER JOIN Customers 
ON Customers.vin = Cars.vin  
WHERE Cars.VIN='$VIN'";
```

Comment: Fixes the multiple records displayed when VSold is set to 'Y', But while VSold is set to 'N' on the Cars table, there will be no VIN set on the Customers table. So Customers.VIN will be null and will never equal Cars.VIN.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT 
  Cars.VIN, Cars.VYear, Cars.VMake, Cars.VModel, Cars.VOdometer,
  Cars.VPurchasedPrice, Cars.VPurchasedDate, Cars.VSold, Cars.VSoldPrice,
  Cars.VSoldDate, Cars.VSalesPerson, Customers.CustFirst, Customers.CustLast 
FROM 
  Cars, Customers 
WHERE 
  Cars.VIN='$VIN'
```

Produces a [cartesian product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cartesian_product) between `cars` and `customers`.  That is, it returns all combinations of rows between the two tables.  To avoid this, you need a join.  If you will always have at least one sold car per customer (ie, it's a sales database), then use an `inner join`.  If, however, you may sometimes have customers that have not bought a car, but still want all customers, then use a `left join`.  This will cause all of the car columns to contain `NULL` if there's not a corresponding record.

```
SELECT 
  Cars.VIN, Cars.VYear, Cars.VMake, Cars.VModel, Cars.VOdometer,
  Cars.VPurchasedPrice, Cars.VPurchasedDate, Cars.VSold, Cars.VSoldPrice,
  Cars.VSoldDate, Cars.VSalesPerson, Customers.CustFirst, Customers.CustLast 
FROM 
  Cars
  LEFT JOIN Customers on Cars.VIN = Customers.VIN
WHERE 
  Cars.VIN='$VIN'
```

Additionally, look into using the mysqli library (or similar) and learn how to parameterize your queries so you can avoid dealing with [SQL Injection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection) later.

Comment: While the Cars.VSold is set to 'N', there will be no customer to associate it to (Customer.VIN). So it works great for cars that have been sold, but isn't pulling anything up when I look up a Car.VIN that hasn't, so the Cars.VIN = Customers.VIN clause will never give me a result.

Comment: Just use `left join` instead.

Comment: No, they are not, besides from the fact that they are both joining tables, they are not alike!. Read `SQL Joins Tutorial` @Martin

Comment: @sagi yes I've realised my mistake. Sorry. I was cross referencing INNER join and LEFT join.